Disabling playback windows 10 notification from top left corner?
I have checked the "similar" question I don't believe the answers there deal with this problem specifically they are mainly talking about the right side notification center, this is not exactly a notification in that sense its a popup that appears on the top left side of the screen , the solutions suggested they all deal with the right side notifs not the one I am talking about here.
The solutions even there are kind of obvious 2 seconds search in the topic not actual solutions that even understand this problem.
I have searched every where online even asked CHATGPT I can't find an answer to this problem, when I am in some other full screen app the mouse goes over to the notification and doesnt stay in the app so its annoying , is there a way to disable this playback notification or just make it 500ms so its not as annoying, there should be a way to do it as there is for most things in windows but I cant seem to figure it out?


I think some of this confusion stems from your use of the word "notification". All the answers suggested so far, and the duplicate, are about actual notifications. You are talking about a media control element that may be called a popup or something else, but is probably not actually a "notification" in the best-understood sense of the word. Changing that may help you.

However, on another note, your combative responses to others attempts to help you will not encourage others to help. I understand it can be frustrating being misunderstood, but do not make this worse by bullying those do spend time and energy trying to help you.

Reading your question you seem to have two related but different issues. Please correct me if I am wrong. You are annoyed at the media control, but you are ALSO annoyed at your mouse jumping over to the media control, presumably interrupting your workflow. Could you clarify whether the biggest issue is your mouse jumping over to the control, or is it the control itself? Please EDIT your post to make that more clear.

To the rest of the community: The marked duplicate is not a duplicate. However, OPs question is unfocused and does not demonstrate any effort they've made to solve the problem themselves except to ask an AI chatbot. I do not think that it should be reopened yet until the most important issue is clarified, and further effort is shown.

Hard to tell from the question. If you mean you want to turn off Windows Notification, use focus assist.

Press Windows, type notifi and select Notifications.
Select Focus assist settings.



In the Focus assist dialog, select

Which notifications should be displayed (none, urgent or all) and
When to apply the focus assist settings (rules).




it's not hard to tell if you check the picture attached, your suggestion talks about the obvious notification center but if you read the question or see the pic i am talking about the pop up on the top left
